# how to make android app work on tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I know most of the android phone app will work on tab but the only difference will be the layout.

Still do I need to add any code in manifest.xml or anywhere else for tablet application ?

I am trying to develop an app for tablet running on 3.0 honeycomb. (trying to change phone 2.1 app to tablet 3.0)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want everything to work exactly the same way, you don't need to change anything. In fact, just having layouts set up for the larger sizes that share names should set it so the same app could be used for both a smaller screen phone and a larger screen tablet.

Comment: By doing a research on google I found this, is this right ? I need to add this:   '<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="11" />'

Comment: You don't need to add targetSdkVersion - the app will run on a tablet by default

Answer (score 1):

**1st Thing:**

You need to include **`<support-screens>`** inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

Include below values inside the `<support-screens>` tag:

```
android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
```

**2nd Thing:**

You need to include  inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. More info [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Include below values inside the `<uses-sdk>` tag:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
          android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
```

Comment: Setting a maxSdkVersion is a really bad idea. This means that anyone on API level 12 (Android 3.1) or higher won't be able to use the app. Also, you shouldn't set a value for [anyDensity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#any) as it's not relevant here.